# Firefox browser not invoking from Selenium Webdriver version 3.4.0

Tags: selenium, firefox

So here is the issue:
Basically I'm trying to invoke Firefox browser with selenium.

```
package basics;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


    public class BrowserInvocation {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
// There is no import option displaying when mouse over FirefoxDriver such as **import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;**
```

Console output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:
>
> FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type at
>   basics.firefox.main(firefox.java:19)

---

I'm using latest versions of all software involve (as of May 15 2017) like firefox, java, eclipse and selenium. I have use 32 bit versions and 64 bit versions. tried removing everything and setup environment again but no luck.

*I have tried invoking chrome in same environment with chrome driver and so far at least I can invoke the browser.*

Comment: Did you try manually entering `import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*`?

Comment: Yes I have tried that.

Comment: which version of geckodriver and Firefox are you using?

Comment: @Jabed Can you please update us with the IDE you are using, if eclipse then version #. Do confirm the Selenium, geckodriver version & Mozilla Firefox version as well. Thanks

Comment: @Jabed Try manually adding `import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;` and execute your code. It may your IDE issue. Thanks